# Project organization and cljsbuild config to require namespace

Tags: compilation, leiningen, clojurescript, cljsbuild

How do I organize my project structure and configure cljsbuild to require my own namespace? For example in my `project/src-cljs` folder I have:

```
└── project
    ├── file1
    │   └── file1.cljs
    ├── file2
    │   └── file2.cljs
    └─── required
        └── required.cljs
```

I'd like `file1.cljs`(namespaced as `file1.file1`) and `file2.cljs`(namespaced as `file2.file2`) to require `required.cljs`(namespaced as `required.required`).

My `:cljsbuild` looks like:

```
:cljsbuild {:builds
            [{:source-paths ["src-cljs/project/file1"]
              :compiler {:output-to "resources/public/js/file1.js"}}
             {:source-paths ["src-cljs/project/file2"]
              :compiler {:output-to "resources/public/js/file2.js"}}]}
```

When I `(:require [required.required :as required])` and compile I get the exception:

`Caused by: clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: No such namespace: required.required, could not locate required/required.cljs, required/required.cljc, or Closure namespace "required.required" at line 1 src-cljs/project/file1/file1.cljs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't usually want a separate js output file and cljsbuild profile for each namespace. You want one single cljsbuild profile including all of your namespaces. Something like:

```
:cljsbuild {:builds
            [{:source-paths ["src-cljs/project"]
              :compiler {:output-to "resources/public/js/project.js"}}]}
```

Not only that: you might want to have ["src-cljs"] as `:source-paths` and then name your namespaces like `project.ns1.sub-ns1`. But you can do it without the `project` ns prefix just fine.

You can find an example of this simple layout in the [simple example project](https://github.com/emezeske/lein-cljsbuild/tree/1.0.6/example-projects/simple) from lein-cljsbuild

Looking to the cljsbuild README, it seems like you were taking the path of ["Multiple build configurations"](https://github.com/emezeske/lein-cljsbuild#multiple-build-configurations). In practice this is mostly used to have separate build profiles for your main code and the tests working against that code. That's shown in the [advanced example](https://github.com/emezeske/lein-cljsbuild/blob/1.0.6/example-projects/advanced/project.clj).